# Force minimize all windows and show the desktop

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop

I'm having problems with minimizing all windows in Windows 7, *including the ones that cannot be minimized*.

When some of windows that cannot be minimized are opened (primarily children dialogue windows), I have no access to the desktop. For example, progress window in some application.

So when Show Desktop button or Win+D is toggled, every window but opened dialogue is minimized, and if a dialogue cannot be moved away (sometimes it can't), it still blocks the desktop. When Show Desktop button is hovered, the desktop can be viewed through dialogue windows (at least with Aero enabled).

Some desktop items cannot be easily reached in another way. Top-level Explorer view (Desktop) provides an alternative, but it isn't nearly as usable as the desktop (Stardock Fences is used to group and unnest the items).

Is there a way to show and operate the desktop, despite opened dialogue windows that cannot be minimized?